# awk: range over match results

Tags: awk

**How to range over `match` results in Awk?**

Found nothing after Googling/SO for 1 hour, and given the expressiveness of Awk, I think there must be a simple method to do this.

Here is an example.

Data:

```
USA [Chicago] [Dallas]
France [Lyon] [Nice]
Italy
UK [London]
```

Awk script:

```
// {
printf "%s: " , $1
# Search for towns
match($0, /\[(.*)\]/, towns)
for (t in towns) {
    printf  "%s;", t
}
printf " \n"
```

}

Run:

```
$ awk -f search.awk dat 
USA: 0start;0length;1start;1length;0;1; 
France: 0start;0length;1start;1length;0;1; 
Italy:  
UK: 0start;0length;1start;1length;0;1;
```

How to obtain something like

```
USA: Chicago;Dallas; 
France: Lyon;Nice;
Italy:  
UK: London;
```

Comment: You code seems to assume double quotes but given sample input doesn't have it. And expected output seems to miss `Nice;`. Can you give a consistent example? Also, does it have to be `awk`? You can use something like `sed -E 's/ |$/: /; s/\[([^]]+)] ?/\1;/g'` for the given sample

Comment: @Sundeep You are right. Edited the post.

Comment: It's not obvious why you'd want to use a loop using `match()` instead of `FPAT` (since you're already using gawk) or some other simpler solution to your actual problem. If you [edit] your question to show more truly representative sample input and expected output then we can help you come up with the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting OP's attempt:

- `match` gives you only the first match, to get all matching occurrences, need to use a loop and continuously adjust the input
- `.*` will give you longest possible match, need to use `[^]]+` instead

```sh
$ cat script.awk
{
    printf "%s: " , $1
    # Search for towns
    while( match($0, /\[([^]]+)]/, m) ){
        printf "%s;", m[1]
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f script.awk ip.txt
USA: Chicago;Dallas;
France: Lyon;Nice;
Italy: 
UK: London;
```

Here's an alternative (assuming you have `GNU awk` based on your `match` usage). The `patsplit` function will return array of all matches and then you can use `substr` to ignore the first character. To do so, the regexp doesn't match the `]`, otherwise you'll have to calculate length of the match and adjust `substr` (or perhaps, use `gsub` to delete first and last character).

```sh
$ cat script.awk
{
    printf "%s: " , $1
    n = patsplit($0, m, /\[[^]]+/)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        printf "%s;", substr(m[i], 2)
    print ""
}
```

I'd prefer `sed` here:

```sh
sed -E 's/ |$/: /; s/\[([^]]+)] ?/\1;/g'
```

Comment: Ok, this is the closest attempt to what I search. Question still open for a little time, in case someone has a really direct proposition (that, from experience in awk, I presume exists).

Comment: @ymudyruc I've added an alternate with `patsplit` that is simpler than `match`, assuming the change in regexp is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this alternate approach that would work with any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk '{s=""; for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) if (gsub(/\[|\]$/, "", $i)) s = s $i ";"; printf "%s: %s\n", $1, s}' file.dat

USA: Chicago;Dallas;
France: Lyon;Nice;
Italy:
UK: London;
```

Comment: Thank you, this could aid in the future. However, the real data are much more complicated, so they are no accessible fields like this. For this reason I tried a grep-like approach, with match().

Comment: @ymudyruc regarding your comment that [the real data are much more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165337/awk-range-over-match-results#comment120475394_68165761) - if you're saying, as I think you are, that the example in your question isn't representative enough of your real data for us to create and test a potential solution using then please edit your question to show an adequate example so no-one else wastes their time trying to help you solve a problem other than the one you actually have.

Comment: @EdMorton No, I mean, this is a MVE. The attemps using other methods are not very applicable in the production code. But the example provided here, **is** representative **for the method expressed in the question**.

Comment: As you can see from all the answers you're getting people are trying to help you come up with a solution to your problem not a fix for your specific implementation of your attempted solution to your problem. It's not obvious that you ONLY want to solve your problem that one way, nor is it clear what would/wouldn't be a workable fix for your attempt given the posted sample input isn't truly representative of your real data in some unspecified way. Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/expected output so we can best help you.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, attempts, please try following code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting RS(record separator) to [ till next occurrence of ] and then substituting [, ] occurrences to null in RT, to get output as per required printed as per shown samples.

```
awk -v RS='\\[[^]]*\\]' 'RT{gsub(/^\[|\]$/,"",RT);ORS=RT} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that places could contain spaces (eg. "New York", "South Korea") but that they don't contain square brackets, you can just:

- replace all occurrences of `] [` with `;`
- replace the final `]` with `;`
- replace first  `[` with `:`
- if no  `[` then replace end of line with `:`

These can be combined into two regular expressions (`]` with optional  `[`;  `[` or end of line), giving:

```
awk '{
    gsub( /\]($|[[:space:]]+\[)/, ";" )
    sub( /$|[[:space:]]+\[/, ": ")
    print
}' dat
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the real data are much more complicated, this was a simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

Super easy with Ruby (which is quite awk like):

```
ruby -lane 's=$F[1..-1].map{|e| e.gsub(/[\[\]]/,"")}.join(";")
puts "#{$F[0]}: #{s}"' file
```

This prints without the trailing `;` which is more typical:

```
USA: Chicago;Dallas
France: Lyon;Nice
Italy: 
UK: London
```

If you want the trailing `;` just add that:

```
ruby -lane 's=$F[1..-1].map{|e| e.gsub(/[\[\]]/,"")}.join(";")
s+=";" if s.length>1
puts "#{$F[0]}: #{s}"' file
```

Prints:

```
USA: Chicago;Dallas;
France: Lyon;Nice;
Italy: 
UK: London;
```

If you want to *range over match results* you can do:

```
ruby -lne '
s1=$_.match(/^([^\[]+)/).captures[0].strip
s2=$_.scan(/\[([^\]]+)/).flatten.join(";")
puts "#{s1}: #{s2}"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a simple `sed` isn't all you need:

```
$ sed 's/] \[/;/g; s/[][]//g; s/[^[:space:]]*/&:/' file
USA: Chicago;Dallas
France: Lyon;Nice
Italy:
UK: London
```

then using GNU awk for FPAT and assuming the data in your question is adequately representative of your real data and that this handles whatever the sed command doesn't adequately:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^][ ]+' -v OFS=';' '{$1=$1": "; sub(OFS,"")} 1' file
USA: Chicago;Dallas
France: Lyon;Nice
Italy:
UK: London
```